# Facebook - Get all meta-tags with the prefix "og:"

Tags: php, facebook, loops, meta-tags

I'm trying to get meta tags from a site, the facebook ogs. I used a class I found online.

```
$metaData = MetaData::fetch('http://www.example.com'); 
foreach ($metaData as $key=>$value){
    if (!is_array($value)){
         echo "$key=>$value";
    }
}
```

The each loop returns the following

```
Content-Type=>text/html; charset=utf-8description=>
og:image=>
og:type=>website
og:site_name=>Site Name
og:url=>www.example.com
```

How do I get values from this results by keys like "**og:url**" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($metaData as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'og:') !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    echo $key . " => " . $value . "\n";
}
```

Is that you want to do?

Comment: Ok this does gets one property, can I get more than one? like og:url, og:site_name?

Answer (score 0):

http://pageno7.com/enrich-your-social-sharing-using-meta-tags/

best ways to learn about the meta tags and also the social sharings